# Really simple question! Which analysis to use?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, t-test

I have two groups of people:

210 people in 2014. 40 of which required an intervention.

A change was made to try and reduce intervention. Then we rechecked:

313 people in 2016. 10 of which required the intervention.

I can see from this that there is a significant decrease in the number of interventions needed. 10 out of 313 vs 40 from 210. However - which statistical test can I use to quantify this?
I had used an unpaired t test and got a power <0.0001. 
Can a t test be used here as we are just looking at intervention required=1 or no intervention = 0?
Thanks

Comment: I know to use t test the groups need to have normal distribution. But is that distribution relating to the intervention or to factors within the populations such as age?

Comment: The title is not informative. It could apply to a large fraction of threads here. Please make it more precise.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a chi-square test (or the equivalent z-test) is more appropriate since you are looking at differences in proportions. A t-test is better suited for testing differences in means.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is more **categorical** by nature (how many participants needed intersession Vs how many didn't) I believe you are looking for [**Fisher's Exact Test**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test).

It will provide a more suitable test of proportions between the two groups.